# Why is Gradle NUnit Plugin failing to execute unit tests?

Tags: gradle, nunit

We're using the NUnit plugin for Gradle "id 'com.ullink.nunit' version '1.8'". When we run the NUnit task that executes our unit tests for the project, we get the following error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':unitTests'.

  > Lorg/gradle/logging/ProgressLogger;

Stack trace shows ClassNotFoundException for ProgressLogger.
Why are we getting this error and how can we fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after upgrading the Gradle Nunut plugin to the latest version.